# Помогите разобраться GuiForm

Tags: java, swing, gui

1) С помощью какого компонента можно разместить вверху вкладки для перехода с одной панели на другую.

2) На кнопку мы создаем слушателя, как сделать так что бы при нажатия на эту кнопку открывалась еще 1 форма, которая нельзя убрать пока мы ее не закроем. И в ней сделать выбор пути для поиска файла?

3) К примеру у меня есть Ексель файл с росш. "csv", что бы его вывести в таблицу на форму, нужно считывать по 1 строке и вносить или сразу считать весь файл и оно отобразит его в таблице?

П.С: Извините за глупые вопросы.

Comment: Swing, JavaFX, что-то другое?

Comment: Извините не увидел ваш комментарий. Swing, Нужно сделать что бы на одной вкладке к примеру были "группы", на другой переход на другое окно " Студенты". И я так понимаю, с помощью "Write" считывать с файла по строке и вносить их в БД + выводить на таблицу.

Comment: Вторую часть я понимаю как реализовать